# Exporting table data to XLSX, but remove columns from export using an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xlsx

I am working on exporting a table's dataset to an XLSX file.  Currently it is working great and I am able remove unwanted columns from the row. But if I want to remove multiple columns from the export, I have to do each one individually (volDeltaVal and workingVolUnt in the example below).  I would like to make this export function reusable, so I have been trying to find a way to pass an array of column names called 'removeFromXlsx' to the 'delete row.****', but have no idea how to do it.  Everything I have tried has resulted in errors. Is there a way to do it?  If so, can someone let me know how?

```
   const removeFromXlsx = [volDeltaVal, workingVolUnt];

   const exportToExcel = () => {
        const tableData = (dataFilteredAndSorted()).map(row => {
            delete row.volDeltaVal
            delete row.workingVolUnt
            return row
        })
        const workSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(tableData);
        const workBook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
        XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(workBook, workSheet, 'records');
        XLSX.write(workBook,{bookType:'xlsx', type:'buffer'});
        XLSX.write(workBook,{bookType:'xlsx', type:'binary'});
        XLSX.writeFile(workBook,'TableData.xlsx');
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I focused only on the dynamic deletion of properties, see if this helps you:

```js
    const dataFilteredAndSorted = () => {
        return [
            { workingVolUnt: 1, volDeltaVal: 10, prop2: 'a', prop1: true },
            { workingVolUnt: 1, volDeltaVal: 10, prop2: 'a', prop1: true },
            { workingVolUnt: 1, volDeltaVal: 10, prop2: 'a', prop1: true },
            { workingVolUnt: 1, volDeltaVal: 10, prop2: 'a', prop1: true },
 ];
    }
    
    const removedProps = (obj, propsArray) => {
        propsArray.forEach(prop => delete obj[prop]);
        return obj;
    }
    
    const propsToDelete = ["volDeltaVal", "workingVolUnt", "prop2"];
    
    const tableData = (dataFilteredAndSorted()).map(row => {
        return removedProps(row, propsToDelete);
    })
    
    console.log(tableData);
```